# gnome-panel doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I wanted to install gnome classic in Ubuntu 12.04, searched on the Ubuntu Software Centre, and it is not there.  I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

and it cannot be found there also.

I also tried installing it on Synaptic Package Manager, and it is not there either.  Is this a problem with the download server, or is it not being distributed or something?  Is there like a .deb file I can install it from?

EDIT:  It seems Gnome desktop environment is also unavailable.